# Use a fixed color set for scatter chart plots

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I have a random color function which generates a different color for every plot in the scatter chart.

```
function getRandomColor() {
                            var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
                            var color = '#';
                            for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                                color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
                            }
                            return color;
                        }
```

But how may I give a fixed color set for the plots?

Answer UPDATE:

```
 var colors = ['red','green','blue','#2A0A0A','#00FF40','#8A4B08',"#610B21","#0A2229","#5E610B","#3B0B2E","#FF0040","#B43104","#0B6121","#01DFA5","#2E2EFE","#DF01A5","#088A4B","#B40431","#1C1C1C","#B45F04"];


    type: 'scatter',
    color: function (color, d) {
        return colors[d.index];
        },
```

Comment: You can use one of the predefined color scales: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#category20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://c3js.org/reference.html#data-color), the color function can receive two parameters, the first being a base color (not sure where this comes from at the moment), and an object holding the data for the point (including the index). You can use this information to determine what color you want from an array of hex color strings.

Example:

```
var colors = ['#1f77b4','#aec7e8','#ff7f0e','#ffbb78'];
...
c3.generate({
data: {
    color:function(color, data){            
        return colors[data.index%colors.length];
        //Example way of picking out your colors from a fixed array
    },
...}
```

Comment: My case is different i can't use data.color, because data.color is use for different legend data, but my plots scatter by one data

Comment: While I'm always glad to have an answer marked up, could you comment on how you used it to solve your problem (or if it was indeed simply the answer)?

Comment: yes it is simply the answer and i insert the color like :type: 'scatter',
        color: function (color, d) {
        return colors[d.index];
       },